# How to report regression test failures to jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, automation

For instance, if regression test is failed then overall report should be failed.

I've configured jenkins with these steps, it gives the code coverage by unit test given by developer if unit tests are executed.

My question is how can I get the code coverage by executing my regression tests which are configured in Post Step.

- Pre Steps: Configuring development environment, like changing some values in configs.
- Pre-Build Step: `clean install -fae -Pcode-coverage -DskipTests` using maven.
- Post Step: 
  Execute Shell - `/var/lib/jenkins/qascripting/Vdopia_Automation/exe/hudson_tc_execute.sh` to trigger my regression test.